# What is Concrete Call and how is it different from Reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection, dagger, dagger-2

I was studying about the [Dagger 2](http://google.github.io/dagger/) - dependency injection library for Android - and in many articles, when the autor compares the Dagger 2 with it's older version ( Dagger ), He says this:

> (...)
>
> The new release, as promised, addresses many of the problems of the original:
>
> - No more reflection — everything is done as concrete calls (ProGuard works with no configuration at all)
>
> (...)

*From:* https://blog.gouline.net/dagger-2-even-sharper-less-square-b52101863542#.w33tjdttt

I know that [Reflection can be used for observing and modifying program execution at runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), but what about these **Concrete Calls**? What are them and how they are different from Reflection?

**Obs.:** Would be great if anyone could provide some sample code/ use case about how to create/ use these Concrete Calls.

Comment: "Concrete calls" refer to just calling a method like you normally would, with `foo.bar()`.  There's nothing special about them, the whole _point_ of them is that they're not special; they're just how you'd write the code normally.

Answer (score 1):

Well...Dagger used some reflection and dagger 2...doesn't.

Dagger 2 uses annotation processing to **generate code** at *compile time*. All those annotations you put on your classes, `@Component`, `@Module`, and so on, signal to the dagger 2 compiler what to do.

It will use them to create a dependency graph, validate it, and then create the code. There are some benefits to this approach, compared to dagger:

- Compile time validation (if you have dependency cycles, or can't provide something, it won't compile and you get an error at *compile time*, and not an exception when running your program)
- Performance (everyting is just simple java—no reflection involved)
- Proguard 'support' (by not relying on reflection, there will be no issues with proguard)

So, as already mentioned in the comments, *concrete calls* in this context would mean the elimination of reflection and generating code. Dagger 2 will produce a whole lot of source files, with which you can also easily debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

Concrete calls are where you call the method directly, and the compiler creates a call instruction:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

This is is the fastest way to call a method, but it only works if you know at compile-time which method you need to call (which is 99% of the time the case). This is how you write code normally.

Sometimes, you don't know what method you need to call. Maybe a user or a file tells you which method you need to call. For this, you need to use reflection. This is much slower, but allows you to dynamically indicate which method to call:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String method = in.next();
// Reflection invocation:
Object result = System.class.getMethod(method).invoke();
System.out.println("Result was: " + result);
```

This would allow you to type `currentTimeMillis` into the command line, and return the value. You could also type `nanoTime` and it would print the result of that too.

Because reflection is an extra layer of indirection (there is no `System.currentTimeMillis()` call in the reflection code above - but it *could* call it!), tools which operate by scanning through the compiled code and rewriting method calls will fail to properly handle reflection calls.